# Identify the Area calling the Master Page

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu, href

I have two Areas in my project Administratives and Applicants.
[Areas in the asp project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwLQh.png)

Both inherit of the master page, now i have in the master page a dropdown menu with a list of items, one has a reference to a link

```
<ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu Orange">   
   <li><a href="https://www.google.com.co/">Home</a></li> 
</ul>
```

What i want to do is change the href according to the Area that is calling the view. I have a specific href for each Area. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think in the master page you can determine what area is currently being served by looking at the `RouteData`:

```
var area = ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];

<ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu Orange">   
  @if(area == "Admin")
  {
     <li><a href="https://www.google.com.co/">Home</a></li> 
  }
  else
  {
     <li><a href="https://www.yahoo.com.co/">Home</a></li> 
  }
</ul>
```